# State In Modal Bottom Sheet in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I would like to know why the state of the below `radio buttons` change post selection whenever the keyboard appears upon clicking on the title `textfield`. Here's how it goes:

The Radio Button named Self comes pre-selected when the `ModalBottomSheet` first comes up. I now select Personal. Also, by default, the Work button also comes pre-selected.

[image]

The moment the keyboard appears, everything gets back to their original state.

[image]

```
openDialog(BuildContext context) {
//final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
showModalBottomSheet(
    shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(10.0))),
    isScrollControlled: true,
    // backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
    backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
    // backgroundColor: Colors.red,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) {
      // bool _show = true;
      int? _radioValue = 0;
      int? _managerValue = 0;
      String? assignedName;

      // void _handleRadioValueChange(value) {
      //   print('RADIO VALUEEEEEEEE: $value');
      // }

      final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
      return StatefulBuilder(builder: (context, setState) {
        return Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(
            bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom,
          ),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              Container(
                      .......
                        child: Column(
                          children: [
                            Row(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Radio(
                                  fillColor: (themeProvider.darkTheme)
                                      ? MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<
                                          Color>((states) {
                                          if (states.contains(
                                              MaterialState.disabled)) {
                                            return Colors.black;
                                          }
                                          return Colors.white;
                                        })
                                      : MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<
                                          Color>((states) {
                                          if (states.contains(
                                              MaterialState.disabled)) {
                                            return Colors.black;
                                          }
                                          return Colors.black;
                                        }),
                                  value: 0,
                                  groupValue: _managerValue,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _managerValue = 0;
                                    });
                                    print("radiofirst" +
                                        value.toString() +
                                        "radiovalue" +
                                        _managerValue.toString());
                                  },
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.person,
                                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width:
                                          SizeVariables.getWidth(context) *
                                              0.007,
                                    ),
                                    const Text(
                                      'Self',
                                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                    width: SizeVariables.getWidth(context) *
                                        0.028),
                                Radio(
                                  fillColor: (themeProvider.darkTheme)
                                      ? MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<
                                          Color>((states) {
                                          if (states.contains(
                                              MaterialState.disabled)) {
                                            return Colors.black;
                                          }
                                          return Colors.white;
                                        })
                                      : MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<
                                          Color>((states) {
                                          if (states.contains(
                                              MaterialState.disabled)) {
                                            return Colors.black;
                                          }
                                          return Colors.black;
                                        }),
                                  value: 1,
                                  groupValue: _managerValue,
                                  onChanged: (value) {
                                    setState(() {
                                      _managerValue = 1;
                                    });
                                    print("radiosecond " +
                                        value.toString() +
                                        "radiovalue " +
                                        _managerValue.toString());
                                  },
                                ),
                                Row(
                                  children: [
                                    Icon(
                                      Icons.group,
                                      color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width:
                                          SizeVariables.getWidth(context) *
                                              0.007,
                                    ),
                                    const Text(
                                      'Assign To',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 16.0,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                            _managerValue == 0
                                ? Row(
                                    mainAxisAlignment:
                                        MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                    children: [
                                      Radio(
                                        fillColor: (themeProvider.darkTheme)
                                            ? MaterialStateProperty
                                                .resolveWith<Color>(
                                                    (states) {
                                                if (states.contains(
                                                    MaterialState
                                                        .disabled)) {
                                                  return Colors.black;
                                                }
                                                return Colors.white;
                                              })
                                            : MaterialStateProperty
                                                .resolveWith<Color>(
                                                    (states) {
                                                if (states.contains(
                                                    MaterialState
                                                        .disabled)) {
                                                  return Colors.black;
                                                }
                                                return Colors.black;
                                              }),
                                        value: 0,
                                        groupValue: _radioValue,
                                        onChanged: (value) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _radioValue = 0;                       //Work
                                          });
                                          print("radiofirst" +
                                              value.toString() +
                                              "radiovalue" +
                                              _radioValue.toString());
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.work,
                                            color: Theme.of(context)
                                                .accentColor,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: SizeVariables.getWidth(
                                                    context) *
                                                0.007,
                                          ),
                                          const Text(
                                            'Work',
                                            style:
                                                TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                      Radio(
                                        fillColor: (themeProvider.darkTheme)
                                            ? MaterialStateProperty
                                                .resolveWith<Color>(
                                                    (states) {
                                                if (states.contains(
                                                    MaterialState
                                                        .disabled)) {
                                                  return Colors.black;
                                                }
                                                return Colors.white;
                                              })
                                            : MaterialStateProperty
                                                .resolveWith<Color>(
                                                    (states) {
                                                if (states.contains(
                                                    MaterialState
                                                        .disabled)) {
                                                  return Colors.black;
                                                }
                                                return Colors.black;
                                              }),
                                        value: 1,
                                        groupValue: _radioValue,
                                        onChanged: (value) {
                                          setState(() {
                                            _radioValue = 1;              //Personal 
                                          });
                                          print("radiosecond " +           
                                              value.toString() +
                                              "radiovalue " +
                                              _radioValue.toString());
                                        },
                                      ),
                                      Row(
                                        children: [
                                          Icon(
                                            Icons.person,
                                            color: Theme.of(context)
                                                .accentColor,
                                          ),
                                          SizedBox(
                                            width: SizeVariables.getWidth(
                                                    context) *
                                                0.007,
                                          ),
                                          const Text(
                                            'Personal',
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                              fontSize: 16.0,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  )
                                : Row(),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
              Form(
                key: _key1,
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    // Container(
                    //   height: SizeVariables.getHeight(context) * 0.1,
                    //   width: double.infinity,
                    //   color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                    // ),
                    Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                          horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
                      child: TextFormField(
                        controller: _taskTitle,
                        cursorColor: Colors.white,
                        // controller: taskController,
                        // maxLines: 5,
                        style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.amber,
                            ),
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                          ),
                          // border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                          //   borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.amber),
                          // ),
                          label: Text(
                            "Task Name",
                            style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1!,
                          ),
                          labelStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyText1,
                          //border: InputBorder.none,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        );
      });
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flutter rebuilds the whole widget when keyboard appears or disappears. So you should use `StatefulWidget` or other state management like `Bloc` to have

```
      int? _radioValue = 0;
      int? _managerValue = 0;
      String? assignedName;
```

For quick fix, just create new `StatefulWidget` and move all your implementation here.

**Edited**

I created new widget here called `YourWidget`, you can use for further.

```
openDialog(BuildContext context) {
//final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
  showModalBottomSheet(
      shape: const RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(top: Radius.circular(10.0))),
      isScrollControlled: true,
      // backgroundColor: Colors.grey[800],
      backgroundColor: Theme
          .of(context)
          .colorScheme
          .onSurfaceVariant,
      // backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        // bool _show = true;

        // void _handleRadioValueChange(value) {
        //   print('RADIO VALUEEEEEEEE: $value');
        // }

        return const YourWidget();
      });
}

class YourWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const YourWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<YourWidget> createState() => _YourWidgetState();
}

class _YourWidgetState extends State<YourWidget> {
  int? _radioValue = 0;
  int? _managerValue = 0;
  String? assignedName;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final themeProvider = Provider.of<ThemeProvider>(context);
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
        bottom: MediaQuery
            .of(context)
            .viewInsets
            .bottom,
      ),
      child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Container(
              //.......
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Radio(
                        fillColor: (themeProvider.darkTheme)
                            ? MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<
                            Color>((states) {
                          if (states.contains(
                              MaterialState.disabled)) {
                            return Colors.black;
                          }
                          return Colors.white;
                        })
                            : MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<
                            Color>((states) {
                          if (states.contains(
                              MaterialState.disabled)) {
                            return Colors.black;
                          }
                          return Colors.black;
                        }),
                        value: 0,
                        groupValue: _managerValue,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _managerValue = 0;
                          });
                          print("radiofirst" +
                              value.toString() +
                              "radiovalue" +
                              _managerValue.toString());
                        },
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            color: Theme
                                .of(context)
                                .accentColor,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width:
                            SizeVariables.getWidth(context) *
                                0.007,
                          ),
                          const Text(
                            'Self',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(
                          width: SizeVariables.getWidth(context) *
                              0.028),
                      Radio(
                        fillColor: (themeProvider.darkTheme)
                            ? MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<
                            Color>((states) {
                          if (states.contains(
                              MaterialState.disabled)) {
                            return Colors.black;
                          }
                          return Colors.white;
                        })
                            : MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith<
                            Color>((states) {
                          if (states.contains(
                              MaterialState.disabled)) {
                            return Colors.black;
                          }
                          return Colors.black;
                        }),
                        value: 1,
                        groupValue: _managerValue,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _managerValue = 1;
                          });
                          print("radiosecond " +
                              value.toString() +
                              "radiovalue " +
                              _managerValue.toString());
                        },
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.group,
                            color: Theme
                                .of(context)
                                .accentColor,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width:
                            SizeVariables.getWidth(context) *
                                0.007,
                          ),
                          const Text(
                            'Assign To',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                  _managerValue == 0
                      ? Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment:
                    MainAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Radio(
                        fillColor: (themeProvider.darkTheme)
                            ? MaterialStateProperty
                            .resolveWith<Color>(
                                (states) {
                              if (states.contains(
                                  MaterialState
                                      .disabled)) {
                                return Colors.black;
                              }
                              return Colors.white;
                            })
                            : MaterialStateProperty
                            .resolveWith<Color>(
                                (states) {
                              if (states.contains(
                                  MaterialState
                                      .disabled)) {
                                return Colors.black;
                              }
                              return Colors.black;
                            }),
                        value: 0,
                        groupValue: _radioValue,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _radioValue = 0; //Work
                          });
                          print("radiofirst" +
                              value.toString() +
                              "radiovalue" +
                              _radioValue.toString());
                        },
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.work,
                            color: Theme
                                .of(context)
                                .accentColor,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: SizeVariables.getWidth(
                                context) *
                                0.007,
                          ),
                          const Text(
                            'Work',
                            style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      Radio(
                        fillColor: (themeProvider.darkTheme)
                            ? MaterialStateProperty
                            .resolveWith<Color>(
                                (states) {
                              if (states.contains(
                                  MaterialState
                                      .disabled)) {
                                return Colors.black;
                              }
                              return Colors.white;
                            })
                            : MaterialStateProperty
                            .resolveWith<Color>(
                                (states) {
                              if (states.contains(
                                  MaterialState
                                      .disabled)) {
                                return Colors.black;
                              }
                              return Colors.black;
                            }),
                        value: 1,
                        groupValue: _radioValue,
                        onChanged: (value) {
                          setState(() {
                            _radioValue = 1; //Personal 
                          });
                          print("radiosecond " +
                              value.toString() +
                              "radiovalue " +
                              _radioValue.toString());
                        },
                      ),
                      Row(
                        children: [
                          Icon(
                            Icons.person,
                            color: Theme
                                .of(context)
                                .accentColor,
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: SizeVariables.getWidth(
                                context) *
                                0.007,
                          ),
                          const Text(
                            'Personal',
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 16.0,
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ],
                  )
                      : Row(),
                ],
              ),
            ),

            Form(
              key: _key1,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  // Container(
                  //   height: SizeVariables.getHeight(context) * 0.1,
                  //   width: double.infinity,
                  //   color: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.onSurfaceVariant,
                  // ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                        horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 20.0),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _taskTitle,
                      cursorColor: Colors.white,
                      // controller: taskController,
                      // maxLines: 5,
                      style: Theme
                          .of(context)
                          .textTheme
                          .bodyText1,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.amber,
                          ),
                        ),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                        ),
                        // border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                        //   borderSide: new BorderSide(color: Colors.amber),
                        // ),
                        label: Text(
                          "Task Name",
                          style: Theme
                              .of(context)
                              .textTheme
                              .bodyText1!,
                        ),
                        labelStyle: Theme
                            .of(context)
                            .textTheme
                            .bodyText1,
                        //border: InputBorder.none,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ]),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How? Can I get an example?

Comment: I'm trying to rewrite your code, but some `)` or `}` are missing, Can you send whole code of `openDialog`

Comment: I tried but Stack overflow has character limitations set for users. However, what I'll do is I'll try adding in the missing ) and }'s

Comment: I updated the answer, please have a look